# If my spellcaster finds someone else's replica, can he recall a different spellcaster's Secret Chest?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, spellcasting

Some other wizard casts [Secret Chest](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/secret-chest) and hides all manner of important treasure on the Ethereal Plane in her well crafted expensive chest. One day later the tiny replica required to retrieve her chest is stolen from her, then misplaced by the thief, then found by my sorcerer.

My sorcerer has never seen this replica before, but has an idea of what he has found and what this replica chest would be used for.

Can my sorcerer retrieve the wizard's chest using her replica?

Does my sorcerer need to cast the spell *Secret Chest* if he has her replica? The spell description says:

> Once the chest is hidden, you can retrieve it by concentrating (a standard action), and it appears next to you.

and

> You need the replica to recall the chest.

Does it make a difference:

a) if my sorcerer has *Secret Chest* on his list of known spells?

b) if he has cast *Secret Chest* on his own small replica to hide his own well crafted expensive chest on the Ethereal Plane? (I don't see how it would make a difference.)

Answer (score 3):

### Only the caster can retrieve the chest

"You" in spell descriptions refers to the caster. So, when the spell says:

> Once the chest is hidden, **you** can retrieve it by concentrating (a standard action), and it appears next to you.

the caster can retrieve it. Not just anyone who has the replica. It is irrelevant in this context if the other person also knows the spell or not.